# Dynamically changing number of columns in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a `JTable` and a `TableModel` that extends `AbstractTableModel`. I would like to dynamically set the number of columns in the table. I implemented this by adding an attribute to my `TableModel` named, `column_count`, and having `getColumnCount` return the `column_count`. I also added a method, `setColumnCount`, that sets `column_count` and calls `fireTableStructureChanged`. Unfortunately, when I ran the program, I kept getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong, or suggest a better solution?

Here's a stack trace:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintGrid(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: perhaps you can add some code for us to see?

Comment: What method is giving you the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?  Can you print a stack trace?

Comment: Can you extend `DefaultTableModel`? It already has `addColumn` method.

Comment: @Dan: what kind of code would be helpful? I don't want to bother others about posting a wall of text.

Comment: @khachik, I guess I could, but I usually prefer using `AbstractTableModel` and this is not part of something bigger, the whole point of this is to make a program capable of handling dynamic column counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exception is caused as follows:

1. You set internal column_count to +1
2. You cause events to be fired which will cause the table to be updated visually
3. When the JTable update code accesses the last column the internal Vector in the column model throws the exception.

The reason is probably because the underlying code of DefaultTableColumnModel does not know about the new column, and its Vector has not properly been altered.

To fix this you should probably write your own custom TableColumnModel which can deal with changing dimensions properly.

Comment: I'm not so sure cause the problem isn't consistent. It's like it depends on timing.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your `getValueAt()` method takes data? If it is an ArrayList and you increase column size, than the table will try to fetch that column from the list and throw an exception.

If that is not the problem, either use DefaultTableModel and [DefaultTableModel.addColumn()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addColumn%28java.lang.Object%29) to add columns, or make sure that you make any changes to the table model from the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: `getValueAt()` uses the formula `(arg0 + 1) * arg1` and I haven't directly messed with the Event Dispatch Thread. All my test application does is create a GUI with a table based on the model, both of which are housed in a 'JScrollPane`. My main function instantiates the GUI and enters a while loop that increments the column count by 1 every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Calling to  method `setModel(tm)` of `JTable` with tm the changed `TableModel`
solved a similar error in my case.